# After git commit, deleted file reappeared in remote repository

Tags: git, github

I have a remote repository on GitHub and a corresponding local repository and workspace.

The issue is like this

1. I pull from remote and start working on the files
2. At the same time, my colleague deletes a file (Bar.java) and modifies a file Foo.java on line 10 and pushes his changes to remote repo.
3. I also make changes to same line of Foo.java
4. I commit my Foo.java and do a Pull to see if any conflicts are there
5. I got and resolved the conflict
6. When I tried to add the changes to index, I got two Files in staging, one is Foo.java which is expected and other is Bar.java which is marked as delete.
7. 1. If I remove deleted file Bar.java from Staging and commits only Foo.java (only my changes) and do a push to upstream, then the deleted file will appear back in Remote Repo!
   2. If add two files into index, commit it and do a push to upstream then only, the deleted file stays deleted in remote repo
      I assume this happens when I do a Pull and there is Conflict and as a result my Local Repo didn't updated but my workspace got updated. Is it correct?

Based on that, I have the following questions:

- How can I make my Local Repository in Sync with Remote Repo when there is a conflict when I do a Pull?
- What happens when I push my local repo to upstream? Will the entire remote repo will be overwritten, or selectively merge my committed changes?

Comment: After you resolve the conflicts, you need to commit that merge to finish the pull (the merge part of the pull is still in progress!).

Comment: I have committed the changes after merging ( only my changes which is in Foo.java ) . But the issue is that i didnt do any changes to Bar.java (which is deleted by another user), it comes as deleted file in my unstaged, i didnt add it to Index. Now when i push that to upstream Bar.java re appears in remote

Comment: You need to re-read what @crashmstr said. When `git merge` or `git pull` detect a merge conflict **it stops the merge**. It staged `bar.java` for deletion (as per the merge) and left `foo.java` for you to clean up. You need to fix `foo.java`, then add that to the index and then commit. This will finalize the merge and commit that `bar.java` is still deleted.

Comment: The merge in progress is the merge from the pull: bringing origin changes into your local repository. Since there was a conflict, that merge *does not complete*. You need to fix the conflict, stage those changes (*all* changes from the pull), and commit. The deleted `Bar.java` is from origin and you need to stage it to complete the pull (otherwise you are changing what the other user did).

Comment: Also, pushing will by default only *add* new commits and the corresponding files to your remote. If for some reason you want to push and remove content in the remote you will need to do a "force push". **This is not recommended unless you know *exactly* what is going to happen when you do**

Comment: @Lasse V. Karlsen - "You need to fix foo.java, then add that to the index and then commit. This will finalize the merge and commit that bar.java is still deleted" – I did exactly the same. But i did not commit staged bar.java . When i pushed to upstream, Bar.java (which is deleted in Remote) appeared again in Remote. It means the deleted file got pushed from my Local to Remote repo. How?

Comment: @Despicableme because you did not merge it correctly *locally*, you *lost* the changes to delete the file because you did not stage and commit the deletion. When a merge has conflicts, you just resolve the conflicts, commit, and push. If `Bar.java` was not in conflict, you stage it, commit, and push just like any other non-conflicting changes from the pull.

Comment: @crashmstr: Thank u. I understood. When there is a conflict i have to stage all changes (from remote) and commit it to my Local. Git could have merged all the changes by itself leaving only conflicts to us to resolve, don't you think?

Comment: @Despicableme - Uh... it did.  At the start of the merge, your index should initially contain the deletion (and as I read step 6 from your list, it sounds like it did); if you un-staged the deletion, that's on you.

Comment: @Mark Adelsberger: true.. i did the un-stage... my bad. But its more like i have to recommit all the changes (other's changes). If there was no conflict, i wouldn't have to commit those changes. To my surprise, git didnt had any track of file that got deleted and undeleted. If i check remote history of Bar.java, i couldn't find, deletion and undeletion

Comment: @Despicableme - Ah, I see... thing is, git organizes changes into commits which, once created, are immutable and somewhat atomic.  To do what you were expecting, it would have to commit the changes that were auto-merged/resolved in one commit, then wait for you to finish conflict resolution so you could commit the others in a second commit. The first commit might well be inconsistent (since it contains some, but not all, changes from the remote); plus the clutter of multiple commits from a merge would be unwelcome (many users don't even like the one commit per merge they already get). ...

Comment: @Despicableme - ... More generally, for git commands that implicitly create a commit, you can expect that if it encounters any difficulty that requires you to intervene, the commit will not yet be created and you have to tell the operation when you've fixed things and it's ok to keep going (often by doing the commit explicitly).

Comment: @Despicableme - One last point (sorry for the long comments): The default log output doesn't show the file as "deleted and recreated" in part because of history simplification. Basically the delete happened on a branch and never affected the mainline so it gets ignored. If you specify `--full-history` option, you should see the commit with the delete (though in that case the squirly `log` output on merges might make things confusing, as you might not explicitly see the file recreated).  But the delete is definitely there in any case, in your coworker's commit.

Comment: @Mark Adelsberger: Thanks a lot Mark for your patience and detailed explanation. It really helped...

Answer (score 2):

To fully understand what's happening (or what it means to be in sync with the remote), we need to remember three types of storage area in git:  work tree, index, database.  You have all three of these locally, and you also care about the database on the remote.

So let's step through a `pull` that has conflicts.  But to make the picture more clear, let's suppose we do a `fetch` first (which is fine, because that's the first step git performs when you ask for a `pull`).

So to start, you have a local repo with commits as

```
I --- A <--(master)(origin/master)
```

You make some changes locally and commit them.

```
I --- A <--(origin/master)
       \
        B <--(master)
```

But meanwhile your coworker pushed changes to the remote, so it has

```
I --- A --- C <--(master)
```

When you `fetch`, you get

```
I --- A --- C <--(origin/master)
       \
        B <--(master)
```

At this point, your database has all of the objects from the remote, so you could say that you're fully in sync with the remote.  The remote is a bit behind on what you have, though; it doesn't know about `B` yet.

Next step of the `pull` is to merge `origin/master` into `master`.  If there are conflicts, then the merge stops with the work tree and index in a "merging" state.  The index contains changes to files that had no conflict, and your worktree contains conflict markers (along with any non-conflicting changes) for files that had conflicts.

These changes are expressed relative to your local master (i.e. relative to `B`) since that's what you're merging into.  So "delete Bar.java" is a change being merged into your local branch without conflict - but you can still override it.  Even though git only *requires* you to deal with the conflicts at this point, you can make whatever changes to the commit as you want.  Allowing that is good and necessary - because sometimes resolving the conflict requires changes outside the region of the actual conflicting lines; but in this case you probably don't want to do it.  So other than `add`ing files as you modify them to resolve conflicts, you should probably leave the index alone.

Finally you've resolved conflicts and commit, so you have

```
I --- A --- C <--(origin/master)
       \     \
        B --- M<--(master)
```

Noe that you've created another new commit (a merge) on your `master`, and the remote is therefore behind until you `push`.  You could avoid this commit by pulling with the `--rebase` option; the process would be similar, but you'd end up with

```
I --- A --- C <--(origin/master)
             \     
              B' <--(master)
```

(where `B'` is the rebased replacement for `B`).  Even so, `origin/master` is behind until you push.

With that background understanding, let's specifically address your questions:

**How can I make my Local Repository in Sync with Remote Repo when there is a conflict when I do a Pull?**

The first step of the `pull` is a `fetch` which does put you fully in sync in the sense that you have all of the information from the remote.  You still have some info that's not yet on the remote (your local commits), and until you've resolved conflicts there's not much you should do about that.

Any perception that you aren't fully in sync is because your worktree and index are reflecting the merge in progress that `pull` initiates after the `fetch`.  (If you had done just a `fetch`, you could immediately `checkout` to `origin/master` and you'd see everything as it is on the remote.)

**What happens when I push my local repo to upstream? Will the entire remote repo will be overwritten, or selectively merge my committed changes?**

A `push` sends updated refs (and other objects as needed to support them) to the remote.  So in this case you're pushing the ref for the `master` branch:

1) git updates the `origin/master` ref in your local repository

2) git makes sure `origin/master` is still "reachable" from `master` (via parent commit pointers); this means, intuitively, that all changes in `origin/master` have been incorporated into `master`, so updating the remotes `master` as requested will only apply new changes that you've locally added to `master`

3) if (2) looks good, then:

3a) required objects are sent to the remote and added to its database.  In this case that would be commits `B` and `M` (or commit `B'` if you did a `rebase`) and objects contained therein.

3b) the remote's `master` ref is updated to match your local `master` ref

While the `master` ref is overwritten, it is not correct to say that the repo is overwritten.  You've mostly added data to it.  Where this can seem a little fuzzy is, the data you've added *can include an instruction to undo a change that had previously been done by someone else*.  Proper handling of the merge step during the pull is what determines if that happens.

Comment: "Any perception that you aren't fully in sync is because your worktree and index are reflecting the merge in progress that pull initiates after the fetch".... "Where this can seem a little fuzzy is, the data you've added can include an instruction to undo a change that had previously been done by someone else. Proper handling of the merge step during the pull is what determines if that happens."...... Thanks for these insights @Mark Adelsberger

Answer (score 1):

If you decide to keep the file on the revision (discarding the deletion) then it will surely show up on the resulting revision. If you decide to follow suit and keep the deletion on the index then the file will be gone.

Comment: Going into another of your questions: "What happens when I push my local repo to upstream? Will the entire remote repo will be overwritten, or selectively merge my committed changes?" There is _no_ merging when you push things to a remote. You ask git to push a revision (through a branch, normally) into a remote branch and that's what git does. If possible (there are no other changes already committed on the remote branch) then it's allowed. If there are already changes on the remote branch that are not part of the revision you are trying to push, it's flat out rejected.

Comment: So it means if my  Local Repo is the latest revision, it will simply "overwrites" the remoted repo , right?

Comment: If you mean _branches_, then yes. Your local branch will replace the remote branch. Repos hold more than branches and if you are providing a branch (say, pushing master) then other branches or tags won't be modified on the remote.

Comment: @Despicableme - Not really.  You never "overwrite" a repo.  You mostly just add commits to it.  I think what you mean to say is, what you push will end up being at the branch tip as a more recent version than what your colleague pushed (which is why the merge caused by the pull should reflect both sets of changes).  But to think of this as overwriting is a murky understanding of how git handles the data and may lead to wrong conclusions.  See my answer for some more details

Comment: Thanks to both of you. I meant to say overwrite branch.